# Upper bound of sum of powers of lowest divisors

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

If $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$, where $p_1$ is lowest prime divisor.
Let $d(n) = \alpha_1$.

Is there any upper bound for $\displaystyle \sum_i^{n} d(i)$?
We can roughly estimate it as $O(n \log n)$, because $d(n) \in O(\log n)$, but maybe exists better estimate for this sum? For example $O(n \log \log n)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get an $O(n \log \log n)$ bound from the obvious estimate
$$d(n) = \alpha_1 \leqslant \alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha_k = \Omega(n)$$
and the rather well-known (e.g. Theorem 430 in Hardy/Wright)
$$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \Omega(n) = x\log \log x + B_2x + o(x)$$
which follows from [Mertens' second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems).

We can get an asymptotically smaller bound, $O(n)$, by using a slightly more conservative bound. With $\omega(n)$ denoting the number of distinct prime factors of $n$, i.e. $\omega(n) = k$ if $n = p_1^{\alpha_1}\ldots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, we can easily see
$$d(n) = \alpha_1 \leqslant 1 + (\alpha_1 - 1) + \ldots + (\alpha_k - 1) = 1 + \Omega(n) - \omega(n)\,.$$
Thus, since (see also Theorem 430 in Hardy/Wright)
$$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \omega(n) = x\log \log x + B_1 x + o(x)$$
we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} d(i)
&\leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \bigl(1 + \Omega(i) - \omega(i)\bigr) \\
&= n + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \Omega(i) - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\omega(i) \\
&= n + (B_2 - B_1)n + o(n)\,.
\end{align}
Since trivially $d(i) \geqslant 1$ for $i > 1$ it follows that
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} d(i) \asymp n\,.$$

Comment: That is really brilliant proof. So can we say, that average $d(n)$ will be $O(1)$?

Comment: More or less. I haven't proved that $d$ really has an average order (that is, that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} d(i)$$ exists), so speaking of the average $d(n)$ is not yet strictly justified. But ignoring that technicality we can say it. However, we must be careful interpreting that. For every given $M$ the set of $n$ with $d(n) > M$ has positive lower asymptotic density (greater than $2^{-(M+1)}$). Nevertheless, such numbers are so rare that it hardly matters in the long run.